# Flutter Upgrade to 3.16 and now it doesn't run

Tags: flutter, flutter-upgrade

## Hey , I updated my flutter version to 3.16 and now I can't run my apps, can someone help me?

The error is the following:

```bash
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Error while evaluating property 'filteredArgumentsMap' of task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'
   > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
      > Failed to transform arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-4a585b79294e830fa89c24924d58a27cc8fbf406.jar (io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-4a585b79294e830fa89c24924d58a27cc8fbf406) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
         > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\arm64_v8a_debug\1.0.0-4a585b79294e830fa89c24924d58a27cc8fbf406\64cc71f9a9c87f7117b3b7e53d399afdd71a9c7e\arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-4a585b79294e830fa89c24924d58a27cc8fbf406.jar.
            > Java heap space
```

And then I tried to increase the heap

```
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

But it didn't work

Here's what appears when I try to see what's my version

```bash
Flutter 3.16.7 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ef1af02aea (26 hours ago) • 2024-01-11 15:19:26 -0600
Engine • revision 4a585b7929
Tools • Dart 3.2.4 • DevTools 2.28.5
```

Comment: Is "flutter doctor -v" happy?  Can you at least run the default "flutter create counter_app"?

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue and i added this configuration in android/app/build.gradle and the app started

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency {
            if ((requested.group == "org.jetbrains.kotlin") && (requested.name.startsWith("kotlin-stdlib"))) {
                useVersion("1.8.0")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i got the solution from here :-
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/119247#issuecomment-1405825291